# Holoviz panel will not print pandas dataframe row in Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, holoviz, panel-pyviz

I'm trying to recreate the first `panel.interact` example in the Holoviz tutorial using a Pandas dataframe instead of a Dask dataframe. I get the slider, but the pandas dataframe row does not show.

See the original example at: http://holoviz.org/tutorial/Building_Panels.html

I've tried using Dask as in the Holoviz example. Dask rows print out just fine, but it demonstrates that panel seem to treat Dask dataframe rows differently for printing than Pandas dataframe rows. Here's my minimal code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import panel
l1 = ['a','b','c','d','a','b']
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':l1,'val':l2})
def select_row(rowno=0):
    row = df.loc[rowno]
    return row
panel.extension()
panel.extension('katex')
panel.interact(select_row, rowno=(0, 5))
```

I've included a line with the `katex` extension, because without it, I get a warning that it is needed. Without it, I don't even get the slider.

I can call the `select_row(rowno=0)` function separately in a Jupyter cell and get a nice printout of the row, so it appears the function is working as it should.

Any help in getting this to work would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution. With Pandas, `loc[rowno:rowno]` returns a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object of length 1 which works fine with `panel` while loc[rowno] returns a `pandas.core.series.Series` object which does not work so well. Thus modifying the `select_row()` function like this makes it all work:

```
def select_row(rowno=0):
    row = df.loc[rowno:rowno]
    return row
```

Still not sure, however, why `panel` will print out the `Dataframe` object and not the `Series` object.

*Note:* if you use `iloc`, then you use add +1, i.e., `df.iloc[rowno:rowno+1]`.